# Apache2 + PHP-FPM - undefined function apache_getenv()

Tags: php, environment-variables, apache2

I have a big problem because for several hours I am trying to run a project that uses SetENV in PHP.
When he even tries to use a simple function apache_getenv();

```
<?php
$ret = apache_getenv("SERVER_ADDR");
echo $ret;
?>
```

I receive a feedback error message

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function apache_getenv() in /var/www/html/env.php:2 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /var/www/html/env.php on line 2
```

Using php-cli the same error. My configuration below.

```
Apache/2.4.34 (Fedora)
PHP 7.2.15 (cli)

# apachectl -M | grep env
env_module (shared)
setenvif_module (shared)
```

Comment: is it enabled in php.ini?

Comment: yes,
variables_order = "EGPCS"

Comment: check if it is not in disabled_functions

Comment: disable_functions is empty.
I do not know if the pricing lies in php-fpm. But there also have clear_env = no

Answer (score 0):

The function apache_getenv() is not available with PHP-FPM.
Simply use getenv() instead of apache_getenv().

```
<?php
$ret = getenv("SERVER_ADDR");
echo $ret;
?>
```

There is usually no reason to use apache_getenv() instead of getenv() now.

Comment: NB: getenv() works for SERVER_ADDR but doesn't work for SSL_PROTOCOL

Comment: You are right, but you can use $ret = getenv("REQUEST_SCHEME"); It will return "http" or "https".