# Call to undefined function apache_getenv() CentOS Stream 9 and PHP 8.1

Tags: php, apache, environment-variables, php-8.1

I get this error:

```
Call to undefined function apache_getenv()
```

I [see suggestions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55172109/apache2-php-fpm-undefined-function-apache-getenv) to just switch to `getenv()`, but I don't see why I should have to since the [manual implies](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.apache-getenv.php) it should be available for PHP 8. I have followed [these instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33777316/php-fatal-error-call-to-undefined-function-apache-getenv) to find that it is not listed in the php.ini disabled functions.

I have tried with SELinux disabled, same problem.  What gives?

One thing that I [read in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69518271/problem-with-apache-getenv-since-upgrading-to-php-8#:%7E:text=Please%20check%20your%20Server%20API%20in%20phpinfo()%20.%20Is%20it%20Apache%202.0%20Handler%20%3F) is that the server API displayed by `phpinfo()` is not Apache, but rather FPM/FastCGI.  But the manual doesn't say anything about this requirement so I'd prefer to continue to use FPM/FastCGI unless I need to change it.

[image]

Any ideas about what is wrong here?

Comment: The function only exists if you're using mod_php under apache. Use `$_SERVER` instead, it's SAPI-agnostic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the ["Introduction" section of the Apache functions documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.apache.php):

> These functions are only available when running PHP as an Apache module.

Your server API is PHP-FPM rather than mod_php, thus the functions are unavailable. This makes sense, because PHP-FPM does not integrate with Apache HTTP Server, it merely receives requests through a socket and sends response back.

I don't know about your exact use case, but `$_SERVER` superglobal array tends to be the most compatible way to fetch information about your environment.